# Performance Improvement For Using BigInteger While Calculating Square Root

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger, bigdecimal, square-root

I am trying to calculate the square root of all the integers below 100 with A precision of up to 10000 digits. I already tried it using Newton's method with Big Decimal, where it eats a lot of time.

So now am using [Jarvis method](http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/maths/jarvisspec02.pdf) for finding the square root using BigInteger.(I think this method involves less number of calculations and gets rid of the maintenance of decimal digits). Even then my code takes a lot of time.The following piece of code depicts the calculations.

```
public class SquareRootHackerRankJarvis {
static BigInteger limit;
static BigInteger a;
static BigInteger b;

private static BigInteger squareroot(int n, int digits, BigInteger ten,
        BigInteger hundred, BigInteger five) {
    limit = ten.pow(digits + 1);
    a = BigInteger.valueOf(n * 5);
    b = BigInteger.valueOf(5);

    while (b.compareTo(limit) == -1) {
        if (a.compareTo(b) != -1) {
            a = a.subtract(b);
            b = b.add(ten);
        } else {
            a = a.multiply(hundred);
            b = (b.divide(ten)).multiply(hundred).add(five);
        }
    }

    return b.divide(hundred);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    int P = scanner.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    int p = 1;
    BigInteger ten = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    BigInteger hundred = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
    BigInteger five = BigInteger.valueOf(5);
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (p * p == i) {
            p++;
            continue;
        }
        BigInteger x = squareroot(i, P, ten, hundred, five);

        char[] digits = x.toString().toCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j <= P - 1; j++) {
            sum += Character.getNumericValue(digits[j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    scanner.close();
}}
```

Can anyone provided  or suggestions about the proper usage of BigInteger for optimum performance?

Comments on improvement of the above algorithm are also welcomed.

Comment: The Jarvis method (and your code, it seems) calculates the square roots of *integers*, not of *irrational numbers* like you claim.

Comment: The code presented irritatingly resembles [MathBlog.dk's](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-80-digits-irrational-square-roots/).

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger ten = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
BigInteger hundred = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
BigInteger five = BigInteger.valueOf(5);
```

Should be moved outside of the function `squareroot` so they are not created and initialized every time function is called. Make sure they are still accessible in this function.

```
BigInteger num;
BigInteger limit;
BigInteger a;
BigInteger b;
```

Should be created outside of the function and should be only initialized on every fucntion call.

Also following line

```
b = (b.divide(ten)).multiply(hundred).add(five);
```

can be optimized to

```
b = b.multiply(ten).add(five);
```

Comment: pulling out `num`, `limit`, `a` and `b` and then re-initializing them on ever call would not make the code threadsafe

Comment: He can use `private static synchronized BigInteger squareroot(int n, int digits)` to deal with this

Comment: In the following step `b = (b.divide(ten)).multiply(hundred).add(five);`, am trying to insert a zero before the last digit. I dont think the approach you gave will achieve this. I have included my entire code. Please see the edited question. Still it takes a lot of time when inputs are 100 (N) and 100000(P).

Comment: Is there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One observation beyond fast computation of numerous digits of roots of non-squares is that there are just 25 non-compound numbers from 2 to 100.

Next, in addition to introducing constants like [Maciej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30758757) suggested, reduce the "introduction of `0` before the trailing `5`" to two operations:

```
static final BigInteger
    ten        = BigInteger.TEN,
    oneHundred = BigInteger.valueOf(100),
    five       = BigInteger.valueOf(  5),
    fourtyFive = BigInteger.valueOf( 45);

/** Computes <code>digits</code> decimal digits of <code>n</code>
 * <em>ignoring</em> (decimal) scaling. */
private static BigInteger sqrtDigitsJarvis(int n, int digits) {
    BigInteger
        limit = ten.pow(digits + 1),     // might be an instance data member
        a = BigInteger.valueOf(n*5L),    // la*100), 
        b = five; // BigInteger.valueOf(ib*10 - 45);
// flawed for limit < sqrt(5n)
    while (b.compareTo(limit) < 0) {
        if (0 <= a.compareTo(b)) { // each branch can be parallelised
            a = a.subtract(b);
            b = b.add(ten);
        } else {
            a = a.multiply(oneHundred);
            b = b.multiply(ten).subtract(fourtyFive);
        }
    }
    return b.divide(oneHundred);
}
```